# How to learn automation from scratch?

Tags: automated-testing

I have zero knowledge about any coding language. But I have to learn an automation tool, preferably selenium. How should I begin? What language should I learn? In short, how to begin??

Comment: Maybe this helps as a starting points: https://ministryoftesting.com/dojo/series/coding-for-non-coders-jim-holmes There are a lot of courses online. Also this question is primairly oppionionated, because popular languages and tools change over time. Even if this is not a duplicate it does not fit the Stack Exchange format. Any learning process starts with research.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a tough question to answer from the start but here is my 2 cents.

1. Pick a language. You need to figure out a language to start with so that you can get a foundation. If you are new to programing at lease learning the fundamentals of a language will help begin building.
2. Learn the basics of the framework I started with Selenium, on Java. Overall in every language that I jumped around to, the basics were similar and interacting with the elements were close to the same. eventually using different languages helped my knowledge grow. By example this is how it went for me:

   - Java Selenium
   - Selenium Cucumber on Ruby
   - Cucumber Selenium Java
   - random PHP frameworks
   - Random frameworks in JS
   - Then Testcafe
   - Python Selenium
3. Consider what do you do as a user? Understand your users workflows. Consider everything you evaluate while testing. Make sure to include or not include those when composing the test.
4. Somethings are not worth automating. Things that are timed events that you can't achieve instantly are not worth the effort. If you have test running on a CI. A test that required 1 hours for a process that gets kicked off is a waste. You can try but just be wary of the tests goal.

At this point you just a have to adventure and play around. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am still learning c#\selenium, but I started with video tutorials on youtube from execute automation. I found them INCREDIBLY helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCO1aucBAJgFR8odzfXOZ5uw

They have videos for other languages and technologies as well.

Comment: online videos are helpful. I know grabbing a book helped me as well.